# fragment analyzing that fragment comes from where in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a method that I send fragment to this as an input parameter:

```
public static void ApishowdetailProducts(final int id, final Fragment 
fragment){}
```

so in this method I want to analyze that this fragment is which one>> I mean that it comes from where : Fragment Home or Fragment Search.

I test it with creating object like these:

```
 final Fragment fh=new FragmentHome();
 final Fragment fs=new FragmentSearch();
 final View v=fragment.getView();

 if (fragment.equals(fs))
 {;}
  if(fragment==fs)
 {;}
```

but it does not work and do not enter in if.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `instanceof`:

```
public static void ApishowdetailProducts(final int id, final Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment instanceof FragmentHome) {
        // Is FragmentHome
    } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentSearch){
        // Is FragmentSearch
    }
}
```

`Equals` will not work since you create a new instance for `fh` and `fs`. See [here](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java) for a good explanation of why this does not work.